# Aurelia bindable attribute with HTML only custom element

Tags: aurelia

Is there documentation that describes the bindable attribute of the a template element

```
<template bindable="router">
```

I did not find anything in aurelia.io.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using bindable attributes in a template, it's because you're creating an HTML only custom element. [From the docs](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-custom-elements/2).